# Released qt .exe won't open on another computer

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, exe, release

I'm using Qt 5.0.2 and made a C++ gui exe program. I released it and added all the needed dlls. I checked with dependency walker. I'm deploying with MSVC2010 32 bit. The program runs perfect on the computer it was built on, but when I try to run it on my brand new, home built computer, nothing shows up when clicked. No errors or anything. I'm using Windows 7 64bit on both computers with SP1 installed and .NET framework 4.5

What would cause my program to not run on my brand new computer?

Comment: .net framework will not help Qt does not use that.

Comment: Beside the point. Just thought I would throw it in there.

Comment: How can you be sure, you have added all needed dlls? Do you have checked with DependencyWalker?

Comment: What compiler did you build Qt and your application with?

Comment: Yes I checked with dependency walker. It gave me no problems

Comment: Did you try installing the microsoft redistributable for 32 bit Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Yes I have it installed on the computer I am releasing from

Comment: Do you get any error dialog when your application starts on the other PC?

Comment: No errors. I open it, and nothing happens

Comment: Did you try starting it from the command prompt?

Comment: Yes and it does the same thing

Comment: It appears to load for a second, then close. Nothing is displayed, but when ran in compatibility mode, the screen just flashes once to compatibility mode then stops.

Comment: Can you see an error in the Windows Event Logs (esp. Application logs) ?

Comment: Nope. no errors found for my program

Comment: What libraries and with what dir structure do you deploy?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/4c1e824412d2ef49b5f38aee7e6531bd oPryzev1.exe is my program. The "stuff" folder contains some source files for the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing some plugins?

```
plugins > platforms > qwindows.dll
```

**The Qt DLL's need them in `platforms` subfolder, without the `plugins` folder!**

Furthermore, it could be necessary to deliver:

```
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this when I have access to my second computer tomorrow. :)